# How To: Center Horizontal Menu & SubMenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I horizontally center this navigation menu and submenu? Setting a smaller navigation list "Width" and setting "Margin:0 auto" does not work. I would also like the keep the background color of the navigation bar across the entire width of the page.

My HTML:

```
<div class="slide-down-page">
    <ul id="nav">
    <li id= "bio"><a class="active btn" href="home.html">Bio</a></li>
    <li id= "portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Writing</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Illustrations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </li>
    <li id= "contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#nav{
margin: 0 ; padding: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background:#e7e7e7;
}

#nav li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}

#nav li a{
padding: 1em 2em;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #F2583E;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
font-size:1.25em;
background: #e7e7e7;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav li a:hover{
background-color: #C1DAD6;
}

#nav a.active, #nav li:hover a.active{
background-color: #F2583E;
color: #F7F3E8;
cursor: default;
}

/*SubMenu*/
#nav li ul{
display: none;
}

#nav li:hover ul{
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 63px;
width: 100%
left:0px;
background: #C1DAD6;
color:white;
}

#nav li:hover ul li, #nav li:hover ul li a{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
color:white;
background: #C1DAD6;
}

#nav li ul li:hover a{
color: #77bed2;
}

#nav li ul li{ 
 _display: inline-block; /* for IE5*/
 }

#nav li ul li a{
width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this with CSS here is the method:

1.remove "float: left;" of "#nav li" and "#nav li:hover ul li, #nav li:hover ul li a"

2.add "text-align: center;" to "#nav"

3.fix "width: 100%" of "#nav li:hover ul" with adding ";" after "width: 100%"

4.add "padding: 0;" to "#nav li:hover ul"

So here is the fixed css code:

```
#nav{
margin: 0 ; padding: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background:#e7e7e7;
text-align:center;
}

#nav li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
}
#nav li a{
padding: 1em 2em;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #F2583E;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
font-size:1.25em;
background: #e7e7e7;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav li a:hover{
background-color: #C1DAD6;
}

#nav a.active, #nav li:hover a.active{
background-color: #F2583E;
color: #F7F3E8;
cursor: default;
}

/*SubMenu*/
#nav li ul{
display: none;
}

#nav li:hover ul{
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 63px;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
left:0px;
background: #C1DAD6;
color:white;
}

#nav li:hover ul li, #nav li:hover ul li a{
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
color:white;
background: #C1DAD6;
}

#nav li ul li:hover a{
color: #77bed2;
}

#nav li ul li{ 
 _display: inline-block; /* for IE5*/
 }

#nav li ul li a{
width: 150px;
}
```